# Why can't I connect to sleeping Xcode server?

Tags: xcode, xcode-server

I have an Xcode server on a separate iMac computer. I use the server for running the tests.

I can connect to the server from a developer computer in Xcode and see the integrations. However when the server iMac goes to sleep mode it is no longer possible to connect to the server.

Here is how I connect to the Server from another Mac.

- Open Xcode Preferences.
- Go to Accounts tab.
- Tap the plus "+" icon on the bottom left and choose "Add Server..." from the menu.
- Finally, enter server's name or IP and login credentials.

When server computer is sleeping Xcode can not connect to the Server.
Is it expected behaviour? Should Xcode server be inaccessible in sleep mode or is it a bug?

OS X 10.11 (15A244d)

OS X Server 4.1.56

Xcode 7.0 (7A176x)